# excel VB copy cells from on sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I´m having problems with my code
I want this code to copy cells from one sheet to another but with the following trick
(english is not my first language, Sorry )

In "sheet1" there is "date and ticket number" always in the same cell, but I also want to copy a list of values that can change in amount...(A10)
all these values go to "sheet2" in the same row... 
"date1" "ticket123" "itemA" "amount"
"date1" "ticket123" "itemB" "amount2"

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

filalibre = Sheets("sheet2").Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
ActiveSheet.Range("a10").Select
fila = 10

While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
Sheets("sheet2").Cells(filalibre, 1) = ActiveSheet.Range("E4") 
Sheets("sheet2").Cells(filalibre, 2) = ActiveSheet.Range("E2") 

Sheets("sheet2").Cells(filalibre, 3) = ActiveSheet.Offset(0, 0) 
Sheets("sheet2").Cells(filalibre, 4) = ActiveSheet.Offset(0, 1) 


filalibre = filalibre + 1

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Wend
Call limpieza
End Sub
```

What can I read to fix this... or can anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned the exact problem or the error you see, I can see some possible sources of an issue.

Replace

```
Sheets("sheet2").Cells(filalibre, 3) = ActiveSheet.Offset(0, 0) 
Sheets("sheet2").Cells(filalibre, 4) = ActiveSheet.Offset(0, 1)
```

By

```
Sheets("sheet2").Cells(filalibre, 3) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0) 
Sheets("sheet2").Cells(filalibre, 4) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
```

Besides this,there are a few other improvements that can be done to your code. But first try to get it working without an error.